# Convert (Dutch) datetime string to datetime format in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime

I have a CSV file that contains information about the period August 22, 2022 up to September 21, 2022. I loaded to CSV into Python using the Pandas library. The timestamps in the CSV file are in a Dutch format (and are strings), i.e., %d-%m-%Y. When I use `pd.to_datetime()` for the timestamps, not all data points are  converted correctly. For example:

| Old (in %d-%m-%Y) | New |
| --- | --- |
| 22-02-22 | 2022-08-22 (%Y-%m-**%d**) |
| 31-08-22 | 2022-08-31 (%Y-%m-**%d**) |
| 01-09-22 | 2022-01-09 (%Y-**%d**-%m) |
| 06-09-22 | 2022-06-09 (%Y-**%d**-%m) |
| 12-09-22 | 2022-12-09 (%Y-**%d**-%m) |
| 13-09-22 | 2022-09-13 (%Y-%m-**%d**) |
| 21-09-22 | 2022-09-21 (%Y-%m-**%d**) |

So, for some data points the months and days are interchanged. I want to convert the strings into the right datetime format. How to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check the docs and specifically the available parameters you can pass to `pd.to_datetime()`?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html you will see that `pd.to_datetime` can take `yearfirst` and `dayfirst` as parameters.

In your case, just pass `dayfirst=True` to it and that's it.

Comment: They need `dayfirst=True` or explicit `format` string

Comment: @buran, `dayfirst=True` worked. Thanks to you both!

Comment: Yes, I got confused, I have edited the answer accordingly. The bottomline is: read the docs and use `yearfirst` or `dayfirst` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the format during conversation because the dates here can be confusing to pandas. The default format is %Y-%m-%d.

So try this instead:

```
df.<your_date_col> = pd.to_datetime(df.<your_date_col>, format='%d-%m-%y')
```